np.ones(30011,30011) needs 7.2GB, but Task Manager shows 5.3GB
A 30,011x30,011 of 64-bit floats takes 7.2GB.  There are many explanations for why one might see np.zeros([30011,30011]) take up (say) a miniscule 0.7MB.  However, my Windows 2010 Task Manager also shows noticeably less memory than expected for np.ones([30011,30011]).  Specifically, 5.3GB, which is  almost 2GB less than the expected 7.2GB.
What is the explanation for this?
Afternote: The 5.3GB includes other objects in the main namespace other than x=np.ones([30011,30011]), albeit smaller objects. Stranger still, x=x*3.14 causes memory usage to drop further to 3GB. It dropped further to 1.7GB within a few minutes even though I didn't do anything.

Are you looking only at RAM usage or are you looking at swap as well ?

Since you don't seem to actually be doing anything with the allocated memory, it can be pushed out to swap space on disk to make room for something making more active use of memory.  I believe Task Manager is showing you what's in RAM at the moment, not the size of your program's entire address space.

o11c & jasonharper: Thanks, I'm just now becoming aware of the distinction between virtual memory and physical memory. This answer shows how to use the Resource Monitor to see virtual and "nonvirtual" memory.  It shows the 7.6GB and 1.5GB under columns "Commit" and "Working Set", respectively.  Since your comments speak to the distinction, would one of you like to post the answer?

I had a hard time finding myself back to the memory display, so here it is for reference: Click the Windows button at the lower left of the desktop, then search for and run perfmon. In the resulting Performance Monitor app, there is a navigation pane on the left side.  Click on the "Performance" line item at the top.  The main area has top and bottom halves, with the top half being "Overview of Performance Monitor".  In that area, click on the "Open Resource Monitor" link. It's actually the Resource Monitor that is launched from the Performance Monitor.

Actually, I can get to the Resource Monitor directly by searching for it after clicking the Windows icon on the lower left corner of the desktop.

The Task Manager shows nonvirtual memory usage, which has a much smaller footprint than the virtual memory used by Python.
The virtual and nonvirtual memory footprint can be seen using Windows 2010's "Resource Monitor" app.  I discovered 3 ways to run it.  The first way: The "Performance" tab of the Task Manager has a link to "Open Resource Monitor".
The second way, which I found online, is more round-about.  It can also be accessed by clicking the Windows button at the lower left of the desktop, then search for and run perfmon.  In the resulting Performance Monitor app, there is a navigation pane on the left side. Click on the "Performance" line item at the top. The main area has top and bottom halves, with the top half being "Overview of Performance Monitor". In that area, click on the "Open Resource Monitor" link.
A 3rd way is to click the Windows icon at the lower left of the desktop and search for "Resource Monitor".
Once in the Resource Monitor is open, there are 2 ways to view the memory usage.  If the "Overview" tab along the top is selected, then there are 4 sections shown, the last of which is "Memory".  In the table therein, the "Commit" columns seems to be the virtual memory while the "Working Set" column is the real memory footprint.
The 2nd way to view memory usage in the Resource Monitor is the select the "Memory" tab along the top.  Again, in the table shown, the "Commit" columns seems to be the virtual memory while the "Working Set" column is the real memory footprint.
Thanks to this Q&A for hinting at the initial (round-about) way to access the Resource Monitor, and to o1cc and jasonharper for indicating the distinction between virtual and nonvirtual memory (in the comments under the originally posted question).
